# Python pyodbc is not recognizing parameter marker. I've supplied 2 markers and two values but its not recognizing them

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

Any idea why the code below would not recognize the first placeholder? I'm assuming I have to put a special character in front of it but i've been unable to find any documentation around it. I've also tried just a simple "create table ?" with no success.

```
for champ in champion_list:
    UPDATE_SQL = """\
        if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name=? and xtype='U')
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[?](
                [champId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [championName] [varchar] NOT NULL,
                [version] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
     """
    values=(champ,champ)
    try:
        cursorprod.execute(UPDATE_SQL, values)
        print str(champ),'table added.'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I get the error

> The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Also, what is `[dbo].[?]` supposed to do? Are you trying to pass the table name as a parameter? I'm pretty sure that this isn't supported but I'm not sure on the syntax you're using in this question.

Comment: Yes i was trying to use a parameter to set the table name. I'm trying to create a table for each item in my list.

Comment: The Actual error is :('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: You will likely have to use string formatting to pass the table name.

Answer (score 2):

Query parameters are for specifying column *values* in DML statements; they cannot be used to specify object (e.g., column or table) *names* in DDL statements. You will need to use dynamic SQL (string substitution) for that ...

... assuming that you really want to create separate tables for each item in the list. If the structure of those tables is identical then that is a bad design. You'd be better served with one table that includes an extra column to identify the list item associated with each row.